# Origine, sens de "Labour de janvier, donne sept pains au dîner." Est-il courant ?

Tags: étymologie, histoire, proverbes

J'ai reçu un message professionnel comportant ce dicton/proverbe. Je l'ai trouvé aussi ici : https://www.proverbes-francais.fr/proverbes-diner/.

Quelle est l'origine de ce dicton ? quel est son sens ? est-il reconnu de nos jours ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Voilà un message bien inhabituel ! Votre interlocuteur est-il féru de français ? :)

Ce dicton n'est pas courant voire oublié en France ; si vous l'utilisez, vous risquez l'incompréhension ou un blanc le temps que la personne réfléchisse au sens du dicton.

Son sens a priori est celui de "qui travaille dur récolte les fruits de son labeur". Il est généralement difficile de retrouver l'origine des dictons vu que ceux-ci sont d'engeance populaire et se perdent dans le temps, à plus forte raison si le dicton en question est tombé en désuétude...

Le labour de janvier suppose un travail âpre, en conditions difficiles. Replacez-vous en contexte : c'est un proverbe qui date a minima du XIXe siècle, avec une population donc essentiellement rurale, qui vit en majorité de l'agriculture et de l'élevage, dans le froid, avec des instruments relativement archaïques et une terre dure. Dans ces conditions, le travail n'était pas une sinécure. On imagine donc ce genre de dicton voir le jour pour se donner du baume au cœur...